# List comprehension to set

Tags: python, data-structures, set

I want to make set with list comprehension, while the output while get multiplied. I try to print with output (list comprehension) with 1 - 5, when i multiplied it with 6 ,the second element not get multiplied properly.

**Input**

```
set1 = set([x for x in range(0, 7)])
set2 = set([x * 2 for x in range(0, 7)])
set3 = set([x * 3 for x in range(0, 7)])
set4 = set([x * 4 for x in range(0, 7)])
set5 = set([x * 5 for x in range(0, 7)])
set6 = set([x * 6 for x in range(0, 7)])
set7 = set([x * 7 for x in range(0, 7)])
set8 = set([x * 9 for x in range(0, 7)])
set9 = set([x * 9 for x in range(0, 7)])

list = [set1, set2, set3, set4, set5, set6, set7, set8, set9]


def set_loop(n):
  b = 0
  for x in n:
    print(x)
    b += 1


set_loop(list)
```

**Output**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/09bMM.png

Comment: 1. Sets are unordered. 2. You can use a set comprehension.

Comment: Why do you want them to be sets? What are you actually trying to accomplish? Side notes: it's probably best not to get into the habit of naming lists `list`, and you can use `print(*your_list, sep='\n')`.

Comment: You're creating and discarding a lot of unnecessary lists.  The first set is just `set(range(7))`.  The second is just `{x*2 for x in range(7)}`.  None of the list you're creating to make the sets are needed.

Comment: Note that `set8` and `set9` are identical.  Presumably the `9` in the creation of `set8` should be `8`.

Comment: Do you have a question?

Answer (score -1):

The code you provided is creating sets of numbers using list comprehensions and then attempting to print these sets. It seems you want to multiply the elements in each set by different factors (from 1 to 9). However, there's a minor issue in your code – you are creating sets, but you want to print the results and not the sets themselves.

```
# Define a function to create a set of values multiplied by a given factor
def create_set(factor):
    return {x * factor for x in range(0, 7)}

# Create a list of sets with different factors
sets_list = [create_set(factor) for factor in range(1, 10)]

# Define a function to print the elements of each set
def print_set_elements(sets):
    for s in sets:
        for element in s:
            print(element)

# Call the function to print the elements of each set
print_set_elements(sets_list)
```

Comment: But sets are ***unordered***, and it seems highly unlikely that the OP doesn't care the order that the items are printed in, so using sets doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Joe Also Sets don't make much sense for another reason - there are no duplicates which would be removed so all they do is jumble up the order in an undefined way.

Comment: ya you both are right but i tried to make the code related to the original given code.